# Send information on program performance

Tags: python, cross-platform, send

I have a library known as [Cyther](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Cyther) that is doing very well, but I need to make sure that it is cross platform. To do this, I'd like to send the `str` variable `data` every time someone runs cyther, to some location that it can be viewed at a later time by me.

I also think this might be a bit risky. Should I ask the user if they wanted to send the data even though it is only one variable? I originally thought of emailing it, but the problem lied in acquiring the users email address, which is out of the question.

Is there any standard protocol for this? Is this even an ethical idea? I want this part of the program to be as simple as possible.

EDIT:

The string is Unicode, and no more than 1000 characters.

I also wouldn't want to send the info to my computer, but instead send it to a external service, or email it to me.

Comment: You should ask permission, and you should remember that many organisations, defence, financial, etc., will not allow *any* external access.  It is also dangerous to you.  One string, but how large?  Can it contain any bit pattern safely?  How robust is your network?  Personally I would restrict this to people you know and trust.

Comment: Not a very pythonic solution, but look at the Maker channel with IFTTT. It's possible to send a request to that in Python, and you trigger that request in IFTTT to email you the contents. I presume they have really good protection on their end, so there's not much to worry about. The main downside is it'll not cope with large strings, so it depends how much you're sending across.